# In eclipse " testng.xml file is invalid" error found in Cucumber-Maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber

While running the feature files in eclipse I'm facing the below Testng.xml file error in Cucumber-Maven project. Please help me  to solve this error.

1. Created the feature file
2. Created Step Definition and Test Runner file.
3. Ran the code through Run Configuration

   ```
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO]  T E S T S
    [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Results:
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
    [INFO] 
    [ERROR] There are test failures.

    Please refer to \\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
    Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date]-jvmRun[N].dump, [date].dumpstream and [date]-jvmRun[N].dumpstream.
    There was an error in the forked process
    Suite file \\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\testng.xml is not a valid file
    org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
    Suite file \\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\testng.xml is not a valid file
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:658)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:533)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:278)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:244)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1194)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1022)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:868)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ LifeModApiAutomation ---
    [INFO] Building jar: \\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\target\LifeModApiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] 
    [INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ LifeModApiAutomation ---
    [INFO] Installing \\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\target\LifeModApiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\rak2\.m2\repository\com\transamerica\LifeModApiAutomation\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\LifeModApiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
    [INFO] Installing \\CRDC3050C2\ta_users\rak2\Ramya Rai\TA Automation Files\LifeModApiAutomation\pom.xml to C:\Users\rak2\.m2\repository\com\transamerica\LifeModApiAutomation\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\LifeModApiAutomation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 04:03 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-17T18:41:02+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 22M/77M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

Comment: Where is this `testng.xml` file? If it's not on a local disk, try putting it on one.

Comment: its already in local disk

Comment: Why do all of the paths it mentions start with \\? It's a bit unusual.

Comment: Its coming automatically. I din mention anywhere